# ValueError while sharing page of Django on facebook

Tags: html, django, facebook, share, pythonanywhere

I have a Django site in pythonanywhere. When I copy and paste the url in facebook to share it, I get this error:

[image]

If you click the link, it works well. I dont know how to access the description of the ValueError.

I have tried this code in the template in order to select the image of thumbnail:

```
<meta content="{{ object.image.url }}" property="og:image"/>
<meta content="TITLE" property="og:title"/>
<meta content="A description" property="og:description"/>
```

But it doesnt work.
I have debug with the facebook tool and I get this report:

> caution-solid Warnings That Should Be Fixed
>
> ```
> Inferred Property
> The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
> Bad Response Code
> URL returned a bad HTTP response code.
> Missing Required Property
> The og:type property is required, but not present.
> Inferred Property
> The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
> Inferred Property
> The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
> Inferred Property
> The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
> Share App ID Missing
> The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog.
> ```

Comment: What does the your logging in django say?..

Comment: Nothing in the log of pythonanywhere. I dont know how to access to the description of ValueError. The link works well

Comment: Is FB caching an old response? If you change your code so that it just returns a very simple static page, do you still see the error?